# this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe() not called on Android device

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 app which I have integrated with Firebase for authentication etc. I want to implement Firebase's cloud messaging so I can push messages to my app on both Android and iOS. I have done this pretty easily on iOS and I have sent a message via Postman which shows on my iPhone and I see the JSON of the message I have sent. When I try it on Android it doesn't work. Both devices receive the message but handle it very diferently.

I have read in a lot of places that you need to set the click_action to FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY but when I do that the app doesn't even open on Android. When I take it out the app loads when you click the message but it doesn't show the body of the message like on iOS in my alert.

```
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';

...

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public fcm: FCM)

...

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
        // Register your new token in your back-end if you want
        // backend.registerToken(token);
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    this.showFailureMessage(error.message);
});
```

This is what I am posting off to... https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"My Title", 
    "body":"My Body", 
    "sound":"default", 
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon",
  },
  "data":{
    "type":"Something", 
  },
    "to":"/topics/all",
    "priority":"high",
    "restricted_package_name":""
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the `data.wasTapped` part in your subscribe. Here, try this:

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
            if (data.wasTapped) {
                alert('Received in background');
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            } else {
                alert('Received in foreground');
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
```